# SaltStack, unable to run custom state modules

Tags: salt-stack

i've recently started using Salt for some automation in our lab.
I've been trying to test out custom states that i can write on my own.
I created a simple test with the following function:

```
def write_text(text, where):

        ret = {'text': text, 'where': where, 'result': False}
        try:
                with open(r''+where, 'w') as file:
                        file.write('this is a test')
                ret['result'] = True
        except:
                ret['result'] = False
        return ret
```

I placed that file in /srv/salt/_states/my_test.py

I also created an sls file at /srv/salt/my_test.sls

```
#Test custom state module
custom_state_test:
  my_test:
    - write_text
    - text: 'this is a test'
    - where: 'C:\text.txt'
```

But whenever i run this on a minion using `salt win64-minion1 state.sls my_test`
(my minions are windows machines) i get the following error

```
win64-minion1:
----------
          ID: custom_state_test
    Function: my_test.write_text
      Result: False
     Comment: State 'my_test.write_text' was not found in SLS 'my_test'
              Reason: 'my_test.write_text' is not available.
     Started:
    Duration:
     Changes:
```

I've followed the guide at SaltStacks docs but still can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: did you try this: `salt '*' saltutil.sync_states`

Comment: Yes I did, didn't help.

Comment: You can always enable debug log_level for master/minion and see if it finds your files at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the minion in a terminal in the foreground in debug mode:

```
salt-minion -l debug
```

Then on the master run:

```
salt '*' saltutil.sync_all

salt win64-minion1 state.sls my_test
```

Check the minion output for any errors or stacktraces.

I know that this is just an example state, but generally a state shouldn't write out a file on it's own, but use Salt's own execution modules to write and read files and otherwise interact with your operating system.